# Shell script if variable equals false? Solaris

Tags: shell, if-statement, solaris-10

All,

At the start of my shell script I set a variable called `filespresent="false"`

This variable acts as a flag to indicate later in my shell script logs if it found a file to process through SQLLoader

The problem is that my if statement is not working it is giving the following error

> [false: not found

Here is my code

```
if ["$filespresent" == "false"]
then
    echo ">>>No CSV files in : " $inbox " folder, skipped SQLLoader" >> script.log
fi
```

I checked the string comparison tutorial here, perhaps Solaris is different to Linux?
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/209/bournebash-shell-scripts-string-comparison/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need spaces around `[` and `]`.  Say:

```
if [ "$filespresent" == "false" ]
```

`[` is a *command*.  Saying `["$filespresent"` causes the shell to interpret it as one token and not a command.

---

The `==` operator is not available in `sh`, use `=` instead:

```
if [ "$filespresent" = "false" ]
```

Comment: Thanks now I get: uknown operator ==

Comment: @serupticious It seems that you're using `sh`.  The `==` operator is not available in `sh`, use `=` instead.  See update above.